# GCC support for cortex-a55

Tags: gcc, arm64, linaro

Can someone please let me know which version of GCC onwards has the support for cortex-a55 as the mtune/mcpu option?

Below is the link mentioning the support has been added, however am unable to correlate which is the exact GNU version this support had been added first. Link for the commit below:-

https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=commit;h=0bf57487e7aeb4794d513e9d124c75cc707c65c7&utm_source=anzwix

Try to map to a version like this for eg:- gcc-linaro-aarch64-linux-gnu-4.9-2014.06-02_linux

Thanks in advance.

---- Merged query ----

How to find version related to a particular GCC commit?

Eg:- https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=commit;h=0bf57487e7aeb4794d513e9d124c75cc707c65c7&utm_source=anzwix

Comment: This sounds like a two-step issue: 1. mapping a given release version to a commit, and 2. checking whether that commit is a descendant of the commit that adds support for your target.

Comment: Hi Siguza, am not sure I understood the second portion of your comment, however #1 will help me, i.e. knowing which GCC version onwards was the fix for cortex-a55 (https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=commit;h=0bf57487e7aeb4794d513e9d124c75cc707c65c7&utm_source=anzwix) added.

Answer (score 1):

GCC 8.1 is the first release that added support for it.
It's in the release notes https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-8/changes.html#aarch64